# how to make date formating consistent in all envirnment

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-formatting

I am using PHP 7.3.

I am trying to format a `strtotime()` format to ISO format, but the result is taking timezone of system, causing inconsistent result in different environment.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 4).'\Z',1585526400);
```

In phpfiddle, the output is `2020-03-30T00:00:00.475Z`, in local system `2020-03-30T05:30:00.415Z` and in server it is `2020-03-30T05:00:00.415Z`.

if I am changing the code to

```
$date = date(DATE_ISO8601, 1585526400);
```

phpfiddle output is `2020-03-30T00:00:00+0000`, local `2020-03-30T05:30:00+0530` and in server `2020-03-30T05:00:00+0500`

How I can make it consistent?

Comment: consistent to what. You want local time? local server time? phpfiddle server time? Which is the time that is consistent to you? PHP is server rendered, hence it always follow server time, and is the source of truth for accurate time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set timezone explicitly. Sample snippet:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimestamp(1585526400);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Comment: For this format it is working fine, can you please give any suggestion, how we can achieve this for `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 4).'\Z'` this format, because for this format, it is still creating different output.

Comment: It should't affect the time zone. Check your logic: you are taking defined previous timestamp (1585526400) without microtime and merging it with current microtime. So microtime will be different every time you invoke function.

Comment: You are correct, here is something http://www.celest-time.org/Php/Time/Instant.html `Instant ofEpochSecond` is doing it correctly, but with core PHP function, I was trying to achieve it, any suggestion on that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the Timezone at the time of getting date and time as:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTime = $dateTime->format("y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $dateTime;
```